# Joining tables with one using EF core column attribute to rename does not output the expected SQL

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Working with a legacy data first application with poor naming conventions.  My SQL output is not what I was expecting.  I'm trying to join and get the "CupsName" aka Name from the CupsName table but it's mapping to CupsNameId

pseudo code

```
 public class CupsName
        {
            public virtual int CupsNameId{ get; set; }

            [Column("CupsName", Order = 2, TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
            public  string Name{ get;}
        }


  var items = await (from c in Context.Cups
                join f in Context.CupsName on c.CupsNameId equals f.CupsNameId
                where c.CupsId == filter.cupsId
                select new Basket
                {
                    CupId = c.CupsId,
                    CupsName= f.Name
                }).ToListAsync
```

Produces:

```
"SELECT [l].[CupsId],
       [l0].[CupsNameId], --This i'm expecting to be Name
"
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using method syntax instead of query syntax for the fix. Not sure why it works differently between the two.